aggregate functions and sorting with subqueries for user traffic analysis
A network device called FortiAnalyzer, there are ready-made queries for obtaining internet usage reports, and we can also customize them ourselves (uses Postgresql). For example, this ready-made query gives us the total bandwidth amount (and etc like threat_block. but sorts by bandwidth, its important) used by source users within the date ranges we specify (before running the query in the GUI).
However, I want to customize it to also find out the destination IP (dstip) and destination interface (dstintf) that each source user has spent the most bandwidth on from their total bandwidth amount (that is, from each source user's total bandwidth data, only find out the destination that used the most bandwidth). I made the following update, but in this form, it does not give me the total bandwidth amount spent by the source and sort accordingly. It sorts by the bandwidth usage to the destinations. What I want is to show the total bandwidth usage of the source user at the end, sort by it, and also find the highest destination for this record in the total source bandwidth usage.
Could you assist with this?
The example ready-made;
SELECT
    f_user,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT srcintf, ',') AS srcintf,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT dev_src, ',') AS dev_src,
    SUM(threatwgt) AS threatweight,
    SUM(threat_block) AS threat_block,
    (SUM(threatwgt) - SUM(threat_block)) AS threat_pass,
    SUM(bandwidth) AS bandwidth,
    SUM(sessions) AS sessions
FROM
    ###(SELECT
            COALESCE(nullifna(`user`),
                     nullifna(`unauthuser`),
                     ipstr(`srcip`)) AS f_user,
            srcintf,
            MAX(COALESCE(srcname, srcmac)) AS dev_src,
            SUM(threatwgt) AS threatwgt,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN (logflag & 2 > 0) THEN threatwgt
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS threat_block,
            SUM(COALESCE(sentdelta, sentbyte, 0) + 
                COALESCE(rcvddelta, rcvdbyte, 0)) AS bandwidth,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN (logflag & 1 > 0) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS sessions
        FROM
            (SELECT
                 `user`,
                 unauthuser,
                 srcip,
                 srcintf,
                 srcname,
                 srcmac,
                 threatweight_sum(threatwgts, threatcnts) AS threatwgt,
                 sentdelta,
                 sentbyte,
                 rcvddelta,
                 rcvdbyte,
                 logflag
             FROM
                 $log-traffic
             WHERE
                 $filter
                 AND (logflag & (1 | 32) > 0)) t
        GROUP BY
            f_user, srcintf
        ORDER BY
            bandwidth DESC)### t
WHERE
    f_user IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    f_user
ORDER BY
    bandwidth DESC

And this is the what I customized;
SELECT
  f_user,
  string_agg(DISTINCT srcintf, ',') AS srcintf,
  string_agg(DISTINCT dev_src, ',') AS dev_src,
  sum(bandwidth) AS bandwidth,
  sum(sessions) AS sessions,
  string_agg(DISTINCT dstip :: TEXT, ',') AS dstip,
  string_agg(DISTINCT dstintf, ',') AS dstintf
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      f_user,
      srcintf,
      dev_src,
      bandwidth,
      sessions,
      dstip,
      dstintf,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY f_user
        ORDER BY
          bandwidth DESC
      ) AS rnk
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          COALESCE(
            nullifna(user),
            nullifna(unauthuser),
            ipstr(srcip)
          ) AS f_user,
          srcintf,
          COALESCE(srcname, srcmac) AS dev_src,
          sum(
            COALESCE(sentdelta, sentbyte, 0) + COALESCE(rcvddelta, rcvdbyte, 0)
          ) AS bandwidth,
          sum(
            CASE
              WHEN (logflag & 1 > 0) THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END
          ) AS sessions,
          dstip,
          dstintf
        FROM
          $log-traffic
        WHERE
          $filter
          AND (logflag & (1 | 32) > 0)
        GROUP BY
          f_user,
          srcintf,
          dev_src,
          dstip,
          dstintf
      ) t
  ) ranked_data
WHERE
  rnk = 1
GROUP BY
  f_user
ORDER BY
  bandwidth DESC


nullifna is not a (standard) PostgreSQL function, what database are you using? Or did you create custom functions? Without data it's also next to impossible to help you

In FortiAnalyzer's documentation it says it uses postgresql, It's probably reprocessing the queries in the background. I don't have any data because it goes to its own database and retrieves the datas with these queries. All I have is the variable names in this ready-made query.

Use a second subquery instead of attempting an "all in one" because the manner of grouping alters for the new need. As you may not be able to use WITH it will be necessary to scan for the source data twice.
SELECT
      fu.*
    , ud.dstip
    , ud.dstintf
    , ud.top_bandwidth
FROM (
    SELECT
          u.f_user
        , STRING_AGG(DISTINCT u.srcintf, ',') AS srcintf
        , STRING_AGG(DISTINCT u.dev_src, ',') AS dev_src
        , SUM(u.threatwgt) AS threatweight
        , SUM(u.threat_block) AS threat_block
        , (SUM(u.threatwgt) - SUM(threat_block)) AS threat_pass
        , SUM(u.bandwidth) AS bandwidth
        , SUM(u.sessions) AS sessions
    FROM (
        SELECT
              COALESCE(nullifna(`user`), nullifna(`unauthuser`), ipstr(`srcip`)) AS f_user
            , srcintf
            , MAX(COALESCE(srcname, srcmac)) AS dev_src
            , SUM(threatwgt) AS threatwgt
            , SUM(CASE WHEN (logflag & 2 > 0) THEN threatwgt ELSE 0 END) AS threat_block
            , SUM(COALESCE(sentdelta, sentbyte, 0) + COALESCE(rcvddelta, rcvdbyte, 0)) AS bandwidth
            , SUM(CASE WHEN (logflag & 1 > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sessions
        FROM (
            SELECT
                 `user`, unauthuser, srcip, srcintf, srcname, srcmac
                , threatweight_sum(threatwgts, threatcnts) AS threatwgt
                , sentdelta, sentbyte, rcvddelta, rcvdbyte, logflag
            FROM $LOG - traffic
            WHERE $FILTER
                AND (logflag & (1 | 32) > 0)
            ) sq
        GROUP BY
              f_user
            , srcintf
        ) u
    WHERE u.f_user IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY u.f_user
    ) fu
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
              f_user, dstip, dstintf, top_bandwidth
            , row_number() over(partition by _user, dstip, dstintf order by top_bandwidth DESC) as rnk
        FROM (
            SELECT
                  COALESCE(nullifna(`user`), nullifna(`unauthuser`), ipstr(`srcip`)) AS f_user
                , dstip
                , dstintf
                , SUM(COALESCE(sentdelta, sentbyte, 0) + COALESCE(rcvddelta, rcvdbyte, 0)) AS top_bandwidth
            FROM (
                SELECT
                     `user`, unauthuser, srcip
                    , sentdelta, sentbyte, rcvddelta, rcvdbyte, logflag, dstip, dstintf
                FROM $LOG - traffic
                WHERE $FILTER
                    AND (logflag & (1 | 32) > 0)
                 ) sq
            GROUP BY
                  f_user
                , dstip
                , dstintf
            ) d
    ) ud on fu.f_user = ud.f_user and ud.rnk = 1
ORDER BY fu.bandwidth DESC


Its still not giving me the total bandwidth.

Are you referring to sum(bandwidth) AS bandwidth or to the top_bandwidth? Which one is not displayed?

Referring to sum(bandwidth) AS bandwidth.

Perhaps a different approach is called for, the revised answer (above original)  adds to the original query and hopefully this will (with reasonable efficiency)  give you what you are seeking.

I gave an error "'group by' or 'order by' clause is expected in hcache". Hcache Aggregation transformed query is https://codefile.io/f/kfXxwnbyHd

With should be the first clause. Not sure if your product will permit it in a lower position. If you can't use WITH, then simply replace "CTE" with the code from that CTE i.e. you need the code in 2 places

Normally it allows to use WITH, for example in the templates has ready-made query with WITH CTE https://codefile.io/f/8TEjExAqU3 . I tried to use WITH in the past and it didn't allow me with the same error but I have no idea why. I looked at using WITH as in this example, but I couldn't do it. I hope you can help me because I'm really obsessed with this.

Just REPEAT the base select including the where clause in both locations where "from CTE" has been used.

Trying this https://codefile.io/f/NYRYxXm92E . And still giving the same error.

Once you replace both "from CTE" you no longer need the WITH clause. see latest answer

Same error with both. I think it needs group by or order by for every select, cant figure it out how to pass that.

Remove "with" altogether. See my latest answer version for an example. If problems persist try separate queries i.e. see if the first query works by itself? then try the second by itself. You do NOT need to order by more than once per query {ignoring any of these over(... order by ...) }

It only works if I put "GROUP BY fu.f_user, fu.srcintf, fu.dev_src, fu.threatweight, fu.threat_block, fu.threat_pass, fu.bandwidth, fu.sessions, ud.dstip, ud.dstintf, ud.top_bandwidth" to the end of the query. But normally it does not fetch any data because of groupping.

I've tried like this and didn't get any error but it says there is no matching log data. https://codefile.io/f/kfXxwnbyHd

Divide it and run as 2 separate queries. This will test if each part actually does what it needs to do and does have data. I cannot do more than make such suggestions.
